# Raster alignment doesn't produce aligned results

Tags: raster, alignment

I have two rasters with different extent and resolution, same coordinate reference, from two different surveys - one RGB and one NIR - takes on different times.

> nir_in
>   class       : RasterBrick 
>   dimensions  : 981, 1232, 1208592, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
>   resolution  : 1.04782e-06, 9.801315e-07  (x, y)
>   extent      : -45.40288, -45.40158, -21.56267, -21.56171  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
>   coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
>
> rgb_in
>   class       : RasterBrick 
>   dimensions  : 978, 1228, 1200984, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
>   resolution  : 1.05155e-06, 9.835644e-07  (x, y)
>   extent      : -45.40288, -45.40159, -21.56272, -21.56176  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
>   coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0

I have aligned both rasters using `align_rgb = resample(rgb_in, nir_in, "bilinear")` and it returned

> align_rgb
>   class       : RasterBrick 
>   dimensions  : 981, 1232, 1208592, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
>   resolution  : 1.04782e-06, 9.801315e-07  (x, y)
>   extent      : -45.40288, -45.40158, -21.56267, -21.56171  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
>   coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0

which seem right, but when I try to plot view the results in QGIS the rasters remains unaligned. I have noticed that the differences are from 6th decimal place onwards.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is your resample in QGIS or ArcGIS? (you don't have a software tag and both platforms have a similar function). If QGIS perhaps this might help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239855/cell-grid-not-aligning-in-qgis

Comment: Thanks Michael. I try to resample in Qgis and R. All return the same result